# Docker: connection refused on exposed port

Tags: http, docker, docker-compose, connection-refused

I have two Docker containers: node-a, node-b. One of them (node-b) should send http request to other (node-a). I'm starting them with Docker Compose. When I'm trying to up them with Compose I face an error:

> Get http://node-a:9098: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:9098: getsockopt: connection refused

EXPOSE is declared in Docker file of a-node:

```
EXPOSE 9098
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'                         
services:                            
    node-a:         
        image: a        
        ports:                       
            - 9098:9098              
        volumes:                     
            - ./:/a-src 
        depends_on:                  
            - redis                  
    node-b:            
        image: b           
        volumes:                     
            - ./:/b-src    
        depends_on:                  
            - node-a
```

Forwarding is enabled. I believe a server starts because it works well without Docker.

Where I should pay attention? What could cause a problem?

#### EDIT:

I've tried to add links but it had no effect:

```
node-b:            
        image: b           
        volumes:                     
            - ./:/b-src 
        links:
            - node-a   
        depends_on:                  
            - node-a
```

Also `links` seemed to be deprecated and does the same thing as `depends_on` in 2+ version of docker-compose.yml:

> docker-compose execute V2 files, it will automatically build a network between all of the containers defined in the file, and every container will be immediately able to refer to the others just using the names defined in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: There is a possibility when node-a has not **yet** opened the port. Could it be?

Comment: @Robert, yes it could be. Also I've tried to use wait-for-it.sh but had no luck. Is there any better ways to sync containers?

Comment: Wait-for-it is currently the best workaround for these cases. Is the node-a app listening to 0.0.0.0 (it must) or just 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Link a container to the service using `links`. ([docker-compose documentation on links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)).

Example:

```
node-b:            
    image: b           
    volumes:                     
        - ./:/b-src    
    depends_on:                  
        - node-a
    links:
        - node-a
```

Comment: I've tried but it had no effect. Please see updates.